# Showing form input data in a different ID in same form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with input textboxes with IDs as follows:

```
#ApplicantFirstName
#ApplicantSurname
#ApplicantAddress
#ApplicantPostcode
```

Later in the form, there is a consent where I need to show the above details in a statement.

I have the consent as follows:

```
<p>I <span id="ApplicantFullName"></span> of <span id="ApplicantFullAddress"></span> hereby give my permission for the company to share personal information with other service providers</p>
```

The function is then triggered on a dropdown being clicked with onclick="updateConsent(); being added to the dropdown.

I have written the following but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function updateConsent(){
      document.querySelectorAll("#ApplicantFirstName, #ApplicantSurname").innerHTML = document.getElementById(ApplicantFullName).innerHTML ;
      document.querySelectorAll("#ApplicantAddress, #ApplicantPostcode").innerHTML = document.getElementById(ApplicantFullAddress).innerHTML ;
   }
</script>
```

Is that the correct script to use?

I'm not getting any errors, just doesn't appear to be working

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: @MartinGodzina `querySelectorAll` is "not working"

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You use `"#ApplicantFirstName, #ApplicantSurname","#ApplicantAddress, #ApplicantPostcode"` but your id in the HTML has the first letter as lower case. Note that Javascript is cAsE sEnSiTivE

Change the Javascript:

```
   function updateConsent(){
      document.querySelectorAll("#applicantFirstName, #applicantSurname").innerHTML = document.getElementById(applicantFullName).innerHTML ;
      document.querySelectorAll("#applicantAddress, #applicantPostcode").innerHTML = document.getElementById(applicantFullAddress).innerHTML ;
   }
```

OR  change the HTML:

```
<p>I <span id="ApplicantFullName"></span> of <span id="ApplicantFullAddress"></span> hereby give my permission for the company to share personal information with other service providers</p>
```